# WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/public/js/dest/dest.js

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, travis-ci

What happened
I use Karma with Mocha to test my code, however it is passed locally on my pc(windows7) and not passed with Travis CI!!

What I do
I just write code to call local Url to request a js file on my project folder, like this...

```
fn('http://localhost:9876/base/public/js/dest/dest.js')
```

and I config my karma like this

```
files: [
   'test/**.js',
   { pattern: 'public/js/dest/*.js', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false }
],

proxies: {
  '/dest.js':'/base/public/js/dest/dest.js'
},
```

it passed on my PC, however my CI log
[what is wrong with CI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtmBn.jpg)

Can Any one tell me how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

HAHA!!!
I finally find i out!!!
It's because in my git commit the dest folder is Wrongly written to `Dest` !!!
However I request with `dest` !!!
so I just delete the `Dest` folder, push to github
and create `dest` folder, push to github
and it's OK !!!